Does the .NET object persistence API limit the fields it fetches to only those in the object?
If I use DynamoDBContext.LoadAsync to get an object and the underlying table has more attributes than what are present in the object, will it automatically limit the attributes to only those needed?

Can't you see in osme tool the query sent to server?
